# Error when creating a new database in openerp 7

Tags: database, postgresql, python-2.7, openerp-7

I try to create a new database using openerp interface, but i receive this error :

```
ProgrammingError: relation "ir_config_parameter" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "ir_config_parameter".id FROM "ir_config_parameter" W...
                                         ^
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you do not have a table name `ir_config_parameter`

Comment: Yes i know, but how can i resolve this probleme ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that I find quite often in openerp 7 (I am not sure about the later versions).  There are various causes.  To debug the error:

1. Verify that the model exist correctly.  In your addons directory/folder there should be a model in the base module.
2. Verify what models was created in postgress using a tool such as pgAdmin III and that all fields were created.
3. Verify that you have the necessary user rights to create the different tables (this should not be a problem - but it is worth a check).
4. Verify that you did not make any changes in the base models that could have lead to the problem - this includes modules that change the base models via inheritance.
5. Verify that the server is properly restarted - this does fix the problem sometimes.
6. Use the command line to update your models.  This also sometimes fix the problem.